# Where-Object and string interpretation

Tags: powershell

Using Where-Object, why does this work..

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_MountPoint | Where-Object {$_.Directory -like 'Win32_Directory (Name = "C:\")'}
```

But this does not:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_MountPoint | Where-Object {$_.Directory -eq 'Win32_Directory (Name = "C:\")'}
```

I'm assuming the -eq operator requires additional quotes, or an issue with the speech marks perhaps.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the `Directory` property contains a nested object, not a string. The equality operator thus compares a `Win32_Directory` object to a string and correctly finds them not equal.

You need to either convert the `Directory` property to an actual string, e.g. like this:

```
... | Where-Object { "$($_.Directory)" -eq 'Win32_Directory (Name = "C:\")' }
```

or like this:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.Directory.ToString() -eq 'Win32_Directory (Name = "C:\")' }
```

or (better) check the relevant property of the nested object, e.g. like this:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.Directory.Name -eq 'C:\' }
```